# How to quantify the patterns of multivariate distribution (e.g. clustered in the center vs. spread out all over the place)?

Tags: measurement, feature-engineering, variable

Is there a well-established way to quantify such patterns (please see the graph)? I guess there should be multiple ways to quantify it or multiple aspects that can be quantified.

The `R` code for generating the plot

```
  set.seed(100)
  par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
  
  a1 <- rnorm(n = 100, mean = 0, sd = 1)
  b1 <- rnorm(n = 100, mean = 0, sd = 1)
  plot(a1 , b1, main = "denser in the center")
  
  a2 <- runif(n = 100, min = -2, max = 2)
  b2 <- runif(n = 100, min = -2, max = 2)
  plot(a2 , b2, main = "'balanced' all over the place")
  
  
  a3 <- c(rnorm(n = 50, mean = -1, sd = 0.5), rnorm(n = 50, mean = 1, sd = 0.5))
  b3 <- c(rnorm(n = 50, mean = -1, sd = 0.5), rnorm(n = 50, mean = 1, sd = 0.5))
  plot(a3 , b3, main = "denser in two corners")
  
  b4 <- c(rnorm(n = 50, mean = -1, sd = 0.3), runif(n = 50, min = -2, max = 2))
  plot(a3 , b4, main = "denser in one coner, spread out elsewhere")
```

[image: Four Type of Patterns]

Answer (score 0):

[This paper](https://docs.lib.purdue.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1117&context=jps) presents an interesting solution:

“Dividing the observed by the expected mean gives the nearest neighbor statistic, R = r0 ⁄ rE, which provides a quantitative summary of the spacing between stimulus elements. The average nearest neighbor distance decreases as points become more tightly clustered; hence, the closer to 0 the value for R becomes. The most tightly clustered situation is that in which all points are superposed, when the value of R equals 0. The closer the points are to being randomly dispersed, the more similar are the values of r0 and rE and the closer to 1 the value for R becomes."